# How can I alias the LINQ results table?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-data

I am trying to alias the LINQ results table, but am not finding any way to do this.

Specifally I am using QueryExtender with a CustomExpression and DynamicData to filter an EntityDataSource.  This works until I sort by the one of the columns, where I get an error that table "it" cannot be found.
I know that this is the table alias that DynamicData wraps everything in.

```
protected void FilterBasedOnDateRange(object sender, CustomExpressionEventArgs e)
{
    if (filterFromDate.SelectedDate != null && filterToDate.SelectedDate != null)
    e.Query = (from p in e.Query.Cast<CalendarDay>()
                where p.CalendarDate >= filterFromDate.SelectedDate && p.CalendarDate <= filterToDate.SelectedDate
                select p);
}


<asp:Label ID="filterFromDateLabel" runat="server" Text='From Date' Font-Bold="true"  />
    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="filterFromDate" runat="server" OnSelectedDateChanged="OnSelectedDateChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
    <asp:Label ID="filterToDateLabel" runat="server" Text='To Date' Font-Bold="true" />
    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="filterToDate" runat="server" OnSelectedDateChanged="OnSelectedDateChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
<br /><br />
<asp:QueryExtender ID="qeRange" runat="server" TargetControlID="GridDataSource">
    <asp:CustomExpression OnQuerying="FilterBasedOnDateRange" />
</asp:QueryExtender>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error was "PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Instance property 'it' is not defined for type "

I found the solution on http://forums.asp.net/p/1528965/3696540.aspx

"Add a selecting event for the entity data source in the List.aspx page template under DynamicData folder, and add the following lines of code in the event."

```
string s=e.SelectArguments.SortExpression; 
if(s.StartsWith("it.")) 
  e.SelectArguments.SortExpression = s.Substring(3);
```

Comment: SortExpression may contains several fields criteria, my approach: `s.Substring(3).Replace(", it.", ", ");`. Also, some one has a more elegant solution, this is just a dirty workaround.